# yq json to yaml add quotes to docker compose labels

Tags: json, docker-compose, yq

I'm trying to create a docker compose override YAML file from JSON, which includes **N** amount of Traefik labels. I currently have the following setup:

```json
{
  "version": "3.7",
  "services": {
    "traefik": {
      "labels": [
        "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[0].main=domain1.local",
        "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[0].sans=*.domain1.local",
        "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[1].main=domain2.local",
        "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[1].sans=*.domain2.local",
        "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[N].main=domainN.local",
        "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[N].sans=*.domainN.local"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

with currently the following command:

```sh
yq e -P docker-compose.override.json
```

Which results in:

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:
  traefik:
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[0].main=domain1.local
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[0].sans=*.domain1.local
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[1].main=domain2.local
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[1].sans=*.domain2.local
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[N].main=domainN.local
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[N].sans=*.domainN.local
```

But I'd like to have double quotes around the traefik labels like so:

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:
  traefik:
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[0].main=domain1.local"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[0].sans=*.domain1.local"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[1].main=domain2.local"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[1].sans=*.domain2.local"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[N].main=domainN.local"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[N].sans=*.domainN.local"
```

How would I achieve this? I'm fine with possibly editing the JSON, but I would prefer a better use of `yq` instead.

Comment: First, yaml is a superset of json, so you can go ahead and run your json file with docker compose. Second, the quotes in yaml are optional. Only when you want a number or some special values as string you need to quote them. So it won't hurt you to not have them quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yq e '... style="" | with(.traefik.labels[] ; . style="double")' docker-compose.override.json`

produces the desired response.

```yaml
version: "3.7"
traefik:
  labels:
    - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[0].main=domain1.local"
    - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[0].sans=*.domain1.local"
    - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[1].main=domain2.local"
    - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[1].sans=*.domain2.local"
    - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[N].main=domainN.local"
    - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[N].sans=*.domainN.local"
```

**Explanation**

- `... style=""` sets pretty print style for all nodes.
- `with(.traefik.labels[] ; . style="double")` sets styling with double quotes for `.traefik.labels` only

Or justs use `yq e '... style="double"' docker-compose.override.json` to enclose the keys into double quotes also.